# Array index out of bounds with random generator

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I am working on my home work and have an issue I cannot sort.  All of this I created and it compiles fine until I tried to test it in the main.  It is giving me the error  in
"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1712741702
    at Test.arrayGen(Test.java:45)
    at Test.main(Test.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
".
```

Here are the methods I created, one for the generation of the arrays and the sort as well as a counter to track the number of changes.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static int selectionSort(int[] data) {

        int min;
        int temp;
        int counter = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < data.length-1; index++) {

            min = index;
  /* Find the minimum element from position index */
            for (int scan = index + 1; scan < data.length; scan++) {
                counter++;
                if (data[scan] < (data[min])) min = scan;
            }

         /* Swap the values */
                temp = data[min];
                data[min] = data[index];
                data[index] = temp;

        }
        return counter;
    }

    public static int[] arrayGen(int max) {
        int top = 100;
        int bottom = 0;
        int listInts;
        Random random = new Random();

        top = 100;

        int[] myList = new int[max];

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            myList[i] = random.nextInt(top - bottom);
            listInts = random.nextInt();
            System.out.println(myList[ listInts]);

        }
        return myList;
    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
        selectionSort(arrayGen(5));

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you believe the range of values returned by `random.nextInt();` to be? Why would you expect it to be a valid array index for `myList`?

Comment: You create a list of a certain size, then try and access the element at the index of a randomly generalted number, without guaranteeing that it within the range, and you're surprised it's out of bounds?

Comment: Were you maybe trying to do `System.out.println(myList[i]);` ? Also, you may just have logic issue in your code. For example, if `top=100; bottom=20`, you'll return results between 0 and 80, not between 20 and 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the critical code:

```
listInts = random.nextInt();
System.out.println(myList[ listInts]);
```

`random.nextInt()` gives you a number between `-2147483648` and `2147483647`

In almost all cases this are no valid array-positions.

Change your for-loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
       myList[i] =  bottom + random.nextInt(top - bottom);
       System.out.println(myList[i]);
}
return myList;
```

this will return a random array with the length of`max` Integers and random values between `bottom` and `top`

Comment: Thank you, that helped!  Now on to the next issue of why my counter isn't returning from the first method.

Comment: What is the expected output? The selection sort is working correct!

Comment: I got it to work, it was something simple I was doing incorrect.  Thanks for your help!